# Assistance Using the CONCAT function in phpMyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, string, phpmyadmin, concatenation

I am finishing up a database project for school and I am having trouble using the CONCAT function in phpMyadmin when running a Query. My table name is 'customer_info' and I have 4 columns. The 2nd and 3rd columns are FirstName and LastName. I have to create a VIEW for the table that includes ALL table data and at the same time Concatenate the Name columns to display with a space between them. I have been searching for a couple hours and no matter what I put together I get errors.

He is a sample of one (of many) I tried:

```
CREATE VIEW `customer_info`  AS
    SELECT
    CustomerID,
    CONCAT(FirstName, " ", LastName) FULL_NAME,
    Contact,
    Location;
```

My focus is primarily Wireless Technology so please have patience with me, I have looked at several SYNTAX definitions for CONCAT or JOIN for strings but no matter what combination I put together I get syntax errors. Please help me to work through this query BUT to understand it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `from` clause.  Something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW v_customer_info AS
    SELECT CustomerID, CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) as FULL_NAME,
           Contact, Location
    FROM customer_info;
```

The view cannot have the same name as the table.

Comment: AH! You are extremely helpful sir, that worked and I now understand where the flaw was with duplicating the view and table name. Thank you so much.

Comment: @JTaylor . . . You can look into the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables.

Comment: @JTaylor . . . Here at Stack Overflow, questions are asked as questions, not comments.  In any case, your questions seem like they are more appropriate for your instructor.